# Split string prior to/or while reading into data frame

Tags: python, dataframe, replace, split, runtime

I have a csv file containing user ids (some of which appear more than once) along with sign up date. Furthermore, I have some information about some paths contained in strings:

```
id1, 01-01-2015, 'place0-place01'
id1, 01-01-2015, 'place0-place01-place03'
id1, 01-01-2015, 'place1-place11-place12'
id2, 01-01-2016, 'place0-place01-place03'
id3, 01-01-2017, 'place5-place51-place53'
id3, 01-01-2017, 'place5-place51-place53'
```

I want to read this into a dataframe and I need to split the strings so that I only get the first part of the string before the first '-'. I've tried using replace and split:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df.replace(row['section'], row['section'].split('.')[0], inplace = True)
```

but this is ridiculously slow due to the size of the file. Does someone have a better solution?
I should end up with:

```
id1, 01-01-2015, 'place0'
id1, 01-01-2015, 'place0'
id1, 01-01-2015, 'place1'
id2, 01-01-2016, 'place0'
id3, 01-01-2017, 'place5'
id3, 01-01-2017, 'place5'
```

or with a count of each path for each user id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.str` suite of `Series` methods. Pandas has a [great tutorial](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#working-with-text-data) on working with Strings.

You can also use the `converters` kwarg in [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

Here are timing results for a few different methods on your dataset (that I duplicated a bunch of times):

```
# 2.78s (Read in everything, split, then take the first result)
%time df = pd.read_csv('tmp.txt', header=None, nrows=1000000); df.loc[:, 2] = df.loc[:, 2].str.split('-').str[0]
# 2.56s (Read in everything and use a regular expression)
%time df = pd.read_csv('tmp.txt', header=None, nrows=1000000); df.loc[:, 2] = df.loc[:, 2].str.extract('([^-]*)')
# 2.58s (Apply a function to the second column when data is read)
%time df = pd.read_csv('tmp.txt', header=None, nrows=1000000, converters={2: lambda x: re.match('[^-]*', x).group(0)})
```

As seen it's a bit faster to do one of the two regex methods (2nd and 3rd).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['place0-place01','place1-place01-place11']})
df['col2'] = df.col1.str.split('-').str.get(0)

    # output
     col1                    col2
0   place0-place01          place0
1   place1-place01-place11  place1
```